# Show estimator is unbiased

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, unbiased-estimator

> Consider the estimator of the variance given by the formula: $(S')^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(Y_i − µ)^2$
>
> Is this
>   a biased or unbiased estimator?

I'm not sure if it is possible to prove this without any additional information. Is there something missing?

Comment: No, nothing is missing.  What is the expected value of $(Y_1-\mu)^2$?

Comment: Oh, the variance, right?

Comment: Well you do have to assume the mean $\mu$ is known to determine the unbiasedness of the variance estimate. Presumably also though not stated in the question is that the $Y_i$ are independent & identically distributed. This is an elementary question. so you should use the self study tag.

Comment: And what is the expected value of the average of a bunch of i.i.d. random variables, all with the same expected value?